# Unable to debug drush command using xdebug with batch api

Tags: drush

I have been debugging drush commands with xdebug and my IDE (currently PHPStorm 7) for a while, but I have been noticing that there are certain commands that die whenever I have the dubegger enabled in the IDE. From what I can tell, it's commands that do batch processing and therefore call drush_backend_batch_process(). In tracking it down as far as it will let me with the debugger, it looks like it dies in _drush_backend_proc_open().

An off the shelf example is the solr-index command in the apachesolr module. I can debug up to the point where drush_backend_batch_process() is called, but it never returns from that call.

Is this a known issue with xdebug on the command line with drush with no way around it? Or is there something I can do in my configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: It dies silently? Or there is some message?

Comment: No, there is nothing. It just hangs, and I have to hit Ctrl-C (or kill the debugger from within the IDE) to be able to get the command line prompt back.

Comment: Oh. Good luck then, I must admit I have no idea. Batch processes are always harder to debug, but never encountered this particular effect.

Answer (score 1):

You're debugging your script using IDE which require valid `xdebug.idekey` to be present in the session which probably isn't passed correctly to the forked process.

It's probably the bug of XDebug (see: [#938](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=938)) which doesn't debug well the forked processes.

I assume you've `xdebug.remote_port` working correctly and there is no any communication issue. Remote debugging generates log file (defined by `xdebug.remote_log`), so you should check further debugger communications details there.

As for workaround, you should debug your script manually by calling the functions: `xdebug_start_trace()` and `xdebug_stop_trace()`.

In case debugging on demand won't work with forked processes, enable `xdebug.auto_trace`, restart Apache, so all forked processes can be debugged properly which will generate huge trace file which you can analyze (defined by `xdebug.trace_output_dir`/`xdebug.trace_output_name`).

Check my [`xdebug.ini`](https://github.com/kenorb/kenorb/blob/master/conf/php/xdebug.ini) for suggestions, especially these settings are useful to see all the details:

```
; Data
xdebug.default_enable = 1           ; bool: The stacktraces will be shown by default on an error event.
xdebug.collect_vars = 1             ; bool: Gather information about which variables are used in a certain scope.
xdebug.show_local_vars=1            ; int: Generate stack dumps in error situations.
xdebug.collect_assignments=1        ; bool: Controls whether Xdebug should add variable assignments to function traces.
xdebug.collect_params=4             ; int1-4: Collect the parameters passed to functions when a function call is recorded.
xdebug.collect_return=1             ; bool: Write the return value of function calls to the trace files.
xdebug.var_display_max_children=256 ; int: Amount of array children and object's properties are shown.
xdebug.var_display_max_data=1024    ; int: Max string length that is shown when variables are displayed.
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=5      ; int: How many nested levels of array/object elements are displayed.
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0             ; int: Show the difference in memory usage between function calls.
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0       ; bool: Show a stack trace whenever an exception is raised.
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200        ; int: Controls the protection mechanism for infinite recursion protection.
```

If XDebug still won't work, then consider using [`phpdbg`](http://phpdbg.com/) instead.

For suggestions how to debug Batch API process, see: [How to debug Batch API more efficiently?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/177923/1908)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue or not; but I THOUGHT I had this issue while running migrations with Drush into Drupal 8 from command line. Would just die and hang on Drush's proc_close.

Apparently, increasing the number of debug connections mattered, inside of my IDE (PHPStorm).

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Simultaneous+debugging+sessions+with+PhpStorm

Perhaps since Batch API makes multiple requests, this is necessary?